# Hide a taskbar toolbar's text and title by default

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-registry, taskbar

I need to add toolbars which hides the shortcut/icon/application text and title as default.

I thought the best way would be through the registry (where everything like that can be set, but not this I guess).

*To be more specific*

`Right click on taskbar` -> `Toolbars` -> `New...`

When you first create a toolbar, the title and toolbar text is enabled by default. Then you would have to unlock the taskbar, rightclick inside the toolbar and untick show text and untick show title.

I need that setting automated and set to not show, through the registry or some other means.

Only thing documented I can find is taskbar settings located at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams\Desktop`

but everything is stored binary there, and I have a feeling if the option to hide text and label is in the registry it would be elsewhere.

Anyone can tell me if/where I can find this in the registry, or by some other means?

Comment: Which toolbar(s) are you talking about?

Comment: Just any on the windows taskbar. You know, Right click -> Toolbars -> New... When you first create a toolbar, the title and toolbar text is enabled by default. you have to : unlock the taskbar, rightclick inside the toolbar and untick show text and untick show title. I need that setting automated and set to not show, through the registry or some other means

Comment: No-one knows this ?

Comment: I'm in the need for this too!

Comment: Same here.  I want Text and Title hidden by default when adding toolbars to Windows 10 taskbar.

Answer (score 6):

Taskbar is locked.  Right-click the taskbar, uncheck "Lock Taskbar".

Then you will have the Text and Title options in the right-click menu for the toolbars.

Comment: Just a note for Windows 10 users who might be reading this: when the taskbar is unlocked and you right-click the toolbar, these settings are located above the normal set of settings you get from right clicking a locked toolbar. I mention this because if you aren't paying very close attention, you won't notice the menu changed what options it contains.